# T-SQL Grouping by unique many-to-many relation performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-performance

I'm trying to create a SQL query which can group by unique many-to-many relationships. I have an *Event* table which can have 1-or-more artists. I would like to group the events *but* only if they don't have same line-up (exactly the same artists performing). If they have exactly the same line-up I would like to get only the newest (=Event Date) event.

After some investigation it seems it will have to be done using an outer apply but I really can't figure it out.

**UPDATE**

*I would require separate rows for each artist, per event, in the result set as described in the Expected Result table. They (or the artist id's) shouldn't be concatenated in a single field.*

**UPDATE 2**

I did get the following query to do what i would is required but the EXISTS condition has poor performance. Can this be re-written in a more performed manner?

Note:
*SQL statements that use the EXISTS condition are very inefficient since the sub-query is RE-RUN for EVERY row in the outer query's table. There are more efficient ways to write most queries, that do not use the EXISTS condition.*

```
 SELECT  E.*
 FROM [Events] AS E
 WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Headliners] AS H
    WHERE H.[EventId] = E.[EventId]
 )
AND NOT EXISTS(
     SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
     FROM [Events] AS E2
     WHERE E2.[Date] < E.[Date] 
     AND NOT EXISTS(
          SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
          FROM [Headliners] AS H1
          WHERE NOT EXISTS(
               SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
               FROM [Headliners] AS [t4]
               WHERE [t4].[EventId] = E.[EventId]
               AND CASE WHEN [t4].[ArtistId] <> H1.[ArtistId] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0) 
         AND H1.[EventId] = E2.[EventId]) 
    AND NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
         FROM [Headliners] AS H2
         WHERE NOT EXISTS(
              SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
              FROM [Headliners] AS [t6]
              WHERE [t6].[EventId] = E2.[EventId]
              AND CASE WHEN [t6].[ArtistId] <> H2.[ArtistId] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0) 
        AND H2.[EventId] = E.[EventId]
     )
 )
```

**Expected Result**

```
 x-----------x---------x------------x----------x
 |  EventId  |   Name  | Date       | ArtistId |
 x-----------x---------x------------x----------x
 |   1       |   E1    | 2016-01-01 | 1        |
 |   1       |   E1    | 2016-01-01 | 2        |
 |   2       |   E2    | 2016-01-02 | 3        |
 |   4       |   E4    | 2016-01-04 | 5        |
 |   4       |   E4    | 2016-01-04 | 6        |
 |   5       |   E5    | 2016-01-05 | 4        |
 |   6       |   E6    | 2016-01-06 | 5        |
 x-----------x---------x------------x----------x
```

**Schema**

[image]

**Event Table**

```
 x-----------x---------x------------x
 |  EventId  |   Name  | Date       |
 x-----------x---------x------------x
 |   1       |   E1    | 2016-01-01 |
 |   2       |   E2    | 2016-01-02 |
 |   3       |   E3    | 2016-01-03 |
 |   4       |   E4    | 2016-01-04 |
 |   5       |   E5    | 2016-01-05 |
 |   6       |   E6    | 2016-01-06 |
 |   7       |   E7    | 2016-01-07 |
 |   8       |   E8    | 2016-01-08 |
 x-----------x---------x------------x
```

**Headliner table**

```
 x-----------x-------------x
 |  EventId  |   ArtistId  |
 x-----------x-------------x
 |   1       |   1         |
 |   1       |   2         |
 |   2       |   3         |
 |   3       |   2         |
 |   3       |   1         |
 |   4       |   5         |
 |   4       |   6         |
 |   5       |   4         |
 |   6       |   5         |
 |   8       |   3         |
 x-----------x-------------x
```

**Artist table**

```
 x------------x---------x--------------x
 |  ArtistId  |   Name  |   Bio        |
 x------------x---------x--------------x
 |   1        |   A1    | BIO1         |
 |   2        |   A2    | BIO2         |
 |   3        |   A3    | BIO3         |
 |   4        |   A4    | BIO4         |
 |   5        |   A5    | BIO5         |
 |   6        |   A6    | BIO6         |
 x------------x---------x--------------x
```

Comment: ... a 404 error page?

Comment: I think your sample and results data is inconsistent with regards to EventId 7 and 8

Comment: @PhilipKelley I don't see the inconsistency. Event 7 has no headliners and 8 has 1 headliner (artist id=3) but this is a duplicate of eventid 2.

Comment: @Jodrell The link should be: http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation but I don't want to concatenate in a single cell but rather have multiple rows returned - see expected result.

Comment: Ah, I missed that NULL. Having "no artists" as a valid result set makes it even trickier.

Comment: This is comparing sets of sets, and picking one from each set of sets. I did something very like this once, and I remember it being crazy hard and complex. (And I can't recall what/where I did this just now...)

Comment: @PhilipKelley the null (no artists) is optional - it could work without that.. and yeah it is complex and i'm having a hard time as well. I hope there is a SQL guru here ;)

Comment: @Frank, I'm suggesting ordered concatenation to find the sets of sets that  match. After that, its relatively trivial to output information about the matches in whatever way you like.

Answer (score 0):

This solution makes the presumption that you can concatenate all the ArtistIds for a given event into a comma-delimited list (with no spaces) that will fit in a `varchar(1000`), which would be 90 if all your ArtistId values are in the billions (10 digits). `Varchar(8000)` would also work, but things might get iffy if you have to use `varchar(max)`.

I used this to set up the data:

```
CREATE TABLE Event
 (
   EventId  int  not null
  ,Name     varchar(50)  not null
  ,Date     date  not null
 )

INSERT Event values
  (1,'E1', 'Jan 1, 2016')
 ,(2,'E2', 'Jan 2, 2016')
 ,(3,'E3', 'Jan 3, 2016')
 ,(4,'E4', 'Jan 4, 2016')
 ,(5,'E5', 'Jan 5, 2016')
 ,(6,'E6', 'Jan 6, 2016')
 ,(7,'E7', 'Jan 7, 2016')
 ,(8,'E8', 'Jan 8, 2016')

CREATE TABLE Headliner
 (
   EventId  int  not null
  ,ArtistId int  not null
 )

INSERT Headliner values
  (1,1)
 ,(1,2)
 ,(2,3)
 ,(3,2)
 ,(3,1)
 ,(4,5)
 ,(4,6)
 ,(5,4)
 ,(6,5)
 ,(8,3)

CREATE TABLE Artist
 (
   ArtistId  int  not null
  ,Name      varchar(50)  not null
  ,Bio       varchar(50)  not null
 )

INSERT Artist values
   (1, 'A1', 'BI01')
  ,(2, 'A2', 'BI02')
  ,(3, 'A3', 'BI03')
  ,(4, 'A4', 'BI04')
  ,(5, 'A5', 'BI05')
  ,(6, 'A6', 'BI06')

SELECT
   EvntId
  ,isnull(
 from Headliner
 group by EventId
```

Next, I created a function to concatenate all ArtistIds for a given EventId:

```
IF objectproperty(object_id('dbo.Concat'), 'isScalarFunction') = 1
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.Concat

GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Concat
 (
  @EventId  int
 )
RETURNS varchar(1000)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Concatenated  varchar(1000)

    SELECT @Concatenated = isnull(@Concatenated + ',' , '') + cast(ArtistId as varchar(10))
     from Headliner
     where EventId = @EventId
     order by ArtistId

    RETURN @Concatenated
END
GO
```

This allows us to use a doubly-nested CTE to do the work. (Could be done with temp tables if performance is an issue, but this seems unlikely.)

```
;WITH cteSetList
 as (--  Build list of artists for each Event, and produce
     --  an ordering on events by date
     select
        EventId
       ,Name
       ,Date
       ,dbo.Concat(EventId)  ArtistList
       ,row_number() over (order by Date)  Ranking
      from Event
    )
 ,cteRankLists
  as (--  Find earliest event for each ArtistList
      select
         ArtistList
        ,min(Ranking)  FirstForList
       from cteSetList
       group by ArtistList
     )
 --  Take that earliest list of artists, join it back to the first query
 --  to get the EventId, join that back to the base tables and we're done
 select
    sl.EventId
   ,sl.Name
   ,sl.Date
   ,he.ArtistId
  from cteRankLists rl
   inner join cteSetList sl
    on sl.Ranking = rl.FirstForList
   left outer join Headliner he
    on he.EventId = sl.EventId
  order by sl.EventId, he.ArtistId
```

Extra bonus, it will even account for "no artist" situations. Performance and other imponderables are dependent upon the size of the tables and sets being worked with.

Comment: @Nielsen I don't want the values concatenated in the result set (see expected results). I would need them to be in separate rows. Thanks for the effort nevertheless.

Comment: Actually, this *does* return the values in separate rows. Try it and see!